# Value of 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' error

Tags: vb.net, minecraft

I am making a launcher for a game (minecraft) but I keep getting this error..
I made it so you open a file (minecraft.exe) via OpenGileDialog then the file name is entered into a text box (textbox1) but in the code I tryed to make it so if the path does not contain "minecraft" is would say Invalid path

here is my code

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    If TextBox1.Contains("Minecraft") = False Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Path")
    End If
End Sub
```

There is an error on TextBox1.Contains("minecraft") = False
it says "Value of 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'"
Please help...

Comment: you realise you're trying to assign `false` to  `TextBox1.Contains("Minecraft")` right? you need to use `==` for comparisons

Comment: Christopher, that'd be news to me. It's VB, not C.

Comment: fair enough, you haven't tagged VB though

Comment: Well, it helps to look at the code which should be glaringly obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `.Text`:

```
If Not TextBox1.Text.Contains("Minecraft") Then
   '...
End If
```

---

`TextBox` inherits from `Control`, which can have children controls. The method `Control1.Contains(Control2)` [expects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.contains%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) another `Control`.

Since you don't have **`Option Strict On`** the copiler is trying to convert the string `"Minecraft"`to a `Control`, giving the exception you're obtaining. I strongly recommend you to use `Option Strict On`on the settings of your projects to avoid further implicit conversions.

You need to access the `TextBox1.Text` property, which returns a `String`, and has the [`.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that you expected, as you can see in the code above.